# ocaml how to test module with concrete types

Tags: inheritance, module, ocaml

Given the following interface:

```
module type Comparable = sig
    type t
    val compare : t -> t -> int
end
```

And the implementation:

```
open Comparable

module Point : Comparable = struct
    type t = {x: float; y: float}

    let compare p1 p2 = 
        match (p1, p2) with
        | {x = x1; _}, {x = x2; _} -> int_of_float (x1 -. x2)
end
```

How would I test `Point`? Or what is the recommended way of doing this?

I tried:

```
let () =
    (Printf.printf "%d\n" (Point.compare {x = 1.2; y = 3.4} {x = 3.5; y = 2.1}));
    ()
```

But got this error in my IDE:

```
Error: Unbound record field x
```

How do I make it so that I can use the type defined within the module without having to resort to exposing that type outside the module?

I'm thinking some sort of `create_from` method, that takes the object type and returns the correct type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you're unintentionally reducing the type precision of your module by using the `Comparable` signature.

That signature is overriding `type t = {x: float; y: float}` to just `type t`, which is why you're getting

```
Error: Unbound record field x
```

A solution would be to simply omit the signature and let OCaml figure it out itself

```
module Point = struct
    type t = {x: float; y: float}

    let compare p1 p2 = 
        match (p1, p2) with
        | {x = x1; _}, {x = x2; _} -> int_of_float (x1 -. x2)
end
```

Then you can do

```
Point.compare {x = 1.2; y = 3.4} {x = 3.5; y = 2.1}
```

Without any error, however you *will* get warning saying that the record type fields are not visible in the current scope — you can fix this by specifying the type of the records:

```
Point.compare {Point. x = 1.2; y = 3.4} {Point. x = 3.5; y = 2.1}
```